# issue arising when one table needs to be connected with two other

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have one table with 3 columns where booking slots are stored(bookID,bookedfrom,bookedfor).
There is a second table which the credentials of the user are stored(crID,email,password).
And there is a 3rd table where endusers are stored(enduserID,name,lastname)

The aim is that the bookedfrom column of the bookingslots table references crID of the credentials table and enduserID of the endusers table.

So we have one column referencing 2 columns in two tables respectively.

Furthermore the endusers table references the credentials table.
You see the point is that while the registered users of the site, their credentials will be held in the credentials table and other data such as name and last name will be held in the end users table-the bookedfrom col in the booking table will reference the crID in the credentials table-...there is the option of booking being made for non registered users,that means there will not be any entry for them in the credentials table but only entry in the endusers table and as such the bookedfrom col must also reference the andusers table.

That being said...I am afraid we might have insertion anomalies were in the booking slots table the bookID might reference a crID of 6 AND a enduserID of 6 again.

What do you think? Are there any problems arising with above schema...like the one mention...here is the sql code:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `appointments`.`appointments` (
`AppointId` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`bookedFrom` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
`bookedFor` INT(11) NOT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`AppointId`) ,
UNIQUE INDEX `bookedFrom_UNIQUE` (`bookedFrom` ASC) ,
UNIQUE INDEX `bookedFor_UNIQUE` (`bookedFor` ASC) ,
CONSTRAINT `fk_appointments_credentials1`
FOREIGN KEY (`bookedFrom` )
REFERENCES `appointments`.`credentials` (`crID` )
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT `fk_appointments_credentials2`
FOREIGN KEY (`bookedFor` )
REFERENCES `appointments`.`credentials` (`crID` )
ON DELETE CASCADE
ON UPDATE CASCADE,
CONSTRAINT `fk_appointments_end_users1`
FOREIGN KEY (`bookedFrom` )
REFERENCES `appointments`.`end_users` (`crID` )
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8

CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `appointments`.`credentials` (
`crID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`email` VARCHAR(255) NULL ,
`password` VARCHAR(100) NULL ,
`hash` VARCHAR(32) NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`crID`) ,
UNIQUE INDEX `email_UNIQUE` (`email` ASC) )
ENGINE = InnoDB
AUTO_INCREMENT = 2
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8


CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `appointments`.`end_users` (
crID` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
name` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
lastname` VARCHAR(100) NULL DEFAULT NULL ,
PRIMARY KEY (`crID`) ,
CONSTRAINT `fk_end_users_credentials1`
FOREIGN KEY (`crID` )
REFERENCES `appointments`.`credentials` (`crID` )
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
```

Comment: What do you mean by "insertion anomalies"?

Comment: An auto-increment field in one table can't be a foreign key to another table. If there's a 1-to-1 correspondence between credentials and end_users, they should just be one table.

Comment: You mean I should merge end_users and credentials? I am trying to find a workaround to that cause I said much code is written based on that design. You said that the referenced table cannot contain auto_increment field and being the foreign key in another table. Yes, but that field is the primary key. How it will be incremented as records are added?